# Resampling an array using predefined indices in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resampling

I have an array of numbers each corresponding to an event and the times when the events occurred. For example,

> ev=[0, 14, 23, 53, 3]
>
> time=[0, 0.4, 0.75, 0.9, 1.1]

Imagine ev vs. time to be a (right-continuous) step function which changes values at the values in the time array. Now by resampling, I mean defining a new array of time values and looking up the values of ev function at these times. I want to resample the variable ev under an evenly spaced time array. For example, if t1 is an evenly spaced array, ev1 is the corresponding event list I need.

> t1=[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2]
>
> ev1=[0, 0, 14, 14, 23, 53, 3]

Is it possible to do such a resampling of an event array in Python? Is there a direct command? Thanks.

Comment: What method are you using to decide on the ev1 values?  **A typical approach to this would be to use an interpolation algorithm, like scipy.interp1d()**, but with the values you give, I'm not sure that would do what you want.

Comment: @tom10: To clarify, imagine ev vs. time to be a (right-continuous) step function which changes values at the values in the time array. Now by resampling, I mean defining a new array of time values and looking up the values of ev function at these times.

Comment: @tom10: Not sure interpd will work. given this is a step function.

Comment: I think then that `interp1d` with `kind="zero"` would work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with `side='right` to find the index of the last item in `time` that is smaller than your new timings, and then use it to fetch values from the `ev` array:

```
>>> np.take(ev, np.searchsorted(time, t1, side='right')-1)
array([ 0,  0, 14, 14, 23, 53,  3])
```

If you first convert `ev` to a numpy array, fancy indecing may be more readable:

```
>>> ev = np.array(ev)
>>> idx = np.searchsorted(time, t1, side='right')-1
>>> ev[idx]
array([ 0,  0, 14, 14, 23, 53,  3])
```

Comment: Thanks. A minor problem with this though. When the dimensions of ev is (5,), it works well. However when they are (5,1) or (1.5), it throws up an error saying "object too deep for desired array". How do I properly reshape the array for using this command?

Comment: If you replace `time` with `time.ravel()` in the call to `searchsorted` it should get rid of that error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a slick sorting way to do this in pure `numpy`, but here's a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) way anyhow.

```
>>> ev = [0, 14, 23, 53, 3]
>>> time = [0, 0.4, 0.75, 0.9, 1.1]
>>> ser = pd.Series(ev, index=time)
>>> ser
0.00     0
0.40    14
0.75    23
0.90    53
1.10     3
dtype: int64
>>> ser.reindex(np.arange(0, 1.4, 0.2), method='ffill')
0.0     0
0.2     0
0.4    14
0.6    14
0.8    23
1.0    53
1.2     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the two variables ev1 and t1 from the two columns of this output?

Comment: @Bravo use `.T` method to transpose the 2D array or `zip(*that_list)`.